# matplotlib how to incrementally add_subplot and render at the end

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to dynamically append axes to a matplotlib figure. In my case, I don't know beforehand how many rows must be drawn/generated. So, In my case, I have a generator method that generates a row number, each call **plot_history** suppose to generate a row with two columns.
So it should incrementally append a row for each call.  show() called later in the code
when all N sub_plot generated.

The logic in code that intended.

```
    add ax1/ax2
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(row_num, 1, 1). ( row = 1,  col 1 , pos 1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(row_num, 2, 2). ( row = 1,  col 2,  pos 2)

    next call 
   
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(row_num, 1, 1). ( row = 2,  col 1 , pos 1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(row_num, 2, 2). ( row = 2,  col 2,  pos 2)
```

Question. I'm not sure maybe it is my misinterpretation of matplotlib doc. It looks like the code is correct but matplotlib show() doesn't render anything. (my understanding show() method generally blocking call so it should block at the end and render and add_subplot suppose append each ax_n to the same figure object). Can someone please explain?

Code below.

```
def plot_history(fig: matplotlib.figure.Figure, hs: History):
    """
    :param fig: is matplotlib.figure.Figure
    :param hs: Keras history
    :return:
    """
    
    # generator generate from 1 to infinity
    row_num = next(row_num_generator)

 
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(row_num, 1, 1)

    try:
        ax1.plot(hs.history['accuracy'])
        ax1.plot(hs.history['val_accuracy'])
    except KeyError:
        ax1.plot(hs.history['acc'])
        ax1.plot(hs.history['val_acc'])

    ax1.title.set_text('Accuracy vs. epochs')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Loss')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Epoch')
    ax1.legend(['Training', 'Validation'], loc='lower right')


    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(row_num, 2, 2)
    ax2.title.set_text('Loss vs. epochs')
    ax2.plot(hs.history['loss'])
    ax2.plot(hs.history['val_loss'])
    ax2.set_ylabel('Loss')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Epoch')
    ax2.legend(['Training', 'Validation'], loc='upper right')
```

```
def main():
  main_figure = plt.figure()

  # compute01 will do a work, call plot_history,  
  # it will add History and call it.
  compute01(main_figure)
  # compute02 will do a work, call plot_history,  
  # it will add History and call it.
  compute02(main_figure)
  ...
  ...
  compute0_N(main_figure)

  main_figure.show()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to do `plt.show()`

Comment: thank you very much @JodyKlymak  that was exactly the issue.